# Bug in paragraph spacing on today's Webby Award Overflow Blog page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, blog

On today's [Vote for Stack Overflow in this year's Webby Awards](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/04/29/vote-for-stack-overflow-in-this-years-webby-awards/?cb=1&_ga=2.266708814.1768426794.1619705084-1111904114.1619705084) page, I spotted an error in the paragraph spacing:

[image]

Separate `<p>` tags are causing that; can we fix it?